# I want to delay a Prototype AJAX form submit?

Tags: ajax, prototypejs

Here is my code:

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {  
        Event.observe('form_post', 'submit', function(){
            new Ajax.Updater('Posts', 'getPosts.php', {
            });
        });
});
```

I just want to delay the call to Updater, any ideas??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap it in a [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/met_win_settimeout.asp) call.

Comment: I second that. Not everything needs a fancy prototypejs function :-)

Answer (score 4):

Use the prototype [delay](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/function/delay) method.

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {  
        Event.observe('form_post', 'submit', function(){
            new Ajax.Updater.delay(1, 'Posts', 'getPosts.php', {
            });
        });
});
```

Comment: I was just typing the same thing. Good call